# Delete row if the column contains text

Tags: vba, excel

I known, this question has been asked thousands of times. But every time I picked up a solution appears error when i debug. (error 1004)

I work with a database with about 300000 lines, where more than half do not care. (I know that have  filter, but wanted to erase to reduce the file and speed up the process).

Then if the column M has a keyword like "water", "beer" or "vodka" it will delete the row. I mean, don't need to be the exact word, just the keyword.

OBS: Row 1 it's a table title with the frozen line.

Thanks!

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works less than 4 seconds for processing your sample data on my machine:

```
Sub QuickDeleteRows()
Dim Sheet_Data As Worksheet, NewSheet_Data As Worksheet, Data As Range
Dim Sheet_Name As String, Text As String, Water As Long, Beer As Long, Vodka As Long

On Error GoTo Error_Handler
SpeedUp True

Set Sheet_Data = Sheets("SOVI")
Sheet_Name = Sheet_Data.Name
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

ReDim Output(1 To LastRow - 1, 1 To 1) As Long

For i = 1 To LastRow - 1
    Text = Cells(i + 1, 13)
    Water = InStr(Text, "water")
    Beer = InStr(Text, "beer")
    Vodka = InStr(Text, "vodka")
    If Water > 0 Or Beer > 0 Or Vodka > 0 Then Output(i, 1) = 1
Next
[S2].Resize(LastRow - 1, 1) = Output

LastColumn = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set Data = Sheet_Data.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

Set NewSheet_Data = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheet_Data)

Data.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="=1"
Data.Copy

With NewSheet_Data.Cells
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    .Cells(1, 1).Select
    .Cells(1, 1).Copy
End With

Sheet_Data.Delete
NewSheet_Data.Name = Sheet_Name
NewSheet_Data.Columns(19).Clear

Safe_Exit:
    SpeedUp False
    Exit Sub
Error_Handler:
    Resume Safe_Exit
End Sub

Sub SpeedUp(SpeedUpOn As Boolean)
With Application
    If SpeedUpOn Then
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    Else
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! Tried here but just create a blank sheet. I put your code in a module

Comment: @user1914644 Put the code in worksheet ("SOVI") code module. If you wanna put it in a module you need change the range reference using `With Sheets("SOVI") ... End With`.

Comment: Here https://app.box.com/s/eb8kb6na1amajv53lfztlpt6304qrgkv tried right now put in the SOVI worksheet, but still make a blank new sheet

Comment: @user1914644 I think I know the problem. You might forget to disable the filter. Try add this line `Sheets("SOVI").AutoFilterMode = False` between `SpeedUp True` and `Set Sheet_Data = Sheets("SOVI")`. It should work fine now. By adding that line, you don't need to disable the filter. Just let me know if there's still a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please post code you've tried first for the community to help you out.  That being said, try this out:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim x as Long
    Dim i as Long

    x = Sheets("SOVI").Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = x to 2 Step -1 
        If InStr(1, Range("M" & i).Value, "water", vbTextCompare) Or InStr(1, Range("M" & i).Value, "beer", vbTextCompare) Or InStr(1, Range("M" & i).Value, "vodka", vbTextCompare) Then
            Range("M" & i).entirerow.delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. But didn't work :/

I uploaded the sample file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25781093/test.xlsb

Comment: See my edited code above.  I changed integers to long because of the number of rows.  I also changed the for loop to step backwards through the rows so as not to miss anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a slightly different approach, with the `Like` and with `Select Case` - this will give you more versatility in the future if you would want to expand it to more types of drinks.

```
Sub FindDrink()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

' always set your sht, modify to your sheet name
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
    Select Case True
        Case (sht.Cells(i, "M").Value Like "*beer*") Or (sht.Cells(i, "M").Value Like "*water*") Or (sht.Cells(i, "M").Value Like "*vodka*")
            Range("M" & i).EntireRow.Delete

        Case Else
            ' if you decide to do other things in the future for other values

    End Select

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If i do not change the line `Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`  to `Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOVI")` to  i got `Run-time error `9`:

Subscript out of range`
And when I change and run the code become really slow

Answer (score 1):

use excel built in filtering functions for the maximum speed

**[Autofilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim keysToErase As Variant, key As Variant

    keysToErase = Array("water", "beer", "vodka") '<--| list your keywords to delete matching column "M" rows with

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False '<--| prevent alerts dialog box from appearing at every rows deletion
    With Workbooks("test").Worksheets("SOVI").Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<--| this gets the range of all contiguous cells to "A1"
        For Each key In keysToErase '<--| loop through keys
            .AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:="*" & key & "*" '<--| filter column "M" with key
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete '<--| delete filtered cells, if any
        Next key
        .Parent.ShowAllData '<--| .. show all rows back...
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True '<--| allow alerts dialog box back
End Sub
```

**[AdvancedFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841242.aspx)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub main2()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False '<--| prevent alerts dialog box from appearing at every rows deletion
    With Workbooks("test").Worksheets("SOVI").Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<--| this gets the range of all contiguous cells to "A1"
        .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=.Parent.Range("U1:U4") '<--| this filters on all keys you placed in cells "U2:U4" with cell "U1" with wanted data header
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete '<--| delete filtered cells, if any
        .Parent.ShowAllData '<--| .. show all rows back...
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True '<--| allow alerts dialog box back
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much s2 I tried to put your code in a module and run the code, but i got `Run-time error `9`:

Subscript out of range`

Comment: which line throws that error? have you changed "test" and "SOVI" with your actual workbook and worksheet names?

Comment: yes. testing the code in same file here. This line: `With Workbooks("test").Worksheets("SOVI").Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<--| this gets the range of all contiguous cells to "A1"` And run the code in Module1

Comment: that error in that line means that when the macro runs either you don't have any open workbook named "test" or this latter has no worksheet named "SOVI"

Comment: That strange. Here the Photo of the visual editor https://app.box.com/s/v113tdlk5qezzvwogsui6m0klijgc2l9

Comment: strange indeed. I replicated the very same condition of yours, but no error on that line. Try typing in the Immediate Window: `?Workbooks("test").Name` and press return. And then the same with `?Worksheets("SOVI").Name`

Comment: @user1914644: did you get through it?

Answer (score 1):

Try with Below code

```
Sub test()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim currentrng As Range
    lastrow = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
        Set currentrng = Range("M" & i)
        If ((currentrng Like "*water*") Or (currentrng Like "*beer*") Or (currentrng Like "*vodka*")) Then
            currentrng.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```